# Is an array from resource xml file ordered?

Tags: android, arrays, xml, kotlin, android-xml

I have two arrays of the same length and I want to get a value from one based on the index of a value from the other. I'm storing the arrays as xml resources in Android.

```
val arrayFromRes1 = resources.getStringArray(R.array.my_first_array)
val arrayFromRes2 = resources.getStringArray(R.array.my_second_array)
```

Will the two arrays always be loaded in the order they appear in the string resources?

Comment: You mean the elements in each array? Can you imagine if it wasn't?! Kind of defeats the purpose of an array.

Comment: So the 2nd item in the first array's xml will always be the second item when loaded this way? (I'm trying to avoid saving an enum map.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Arrays are ordered.

---

If they weren't, chaos would ensue.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but if you add a yes and a reference link I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Drew You want a reference to what, exactly? It's an *array*. Arrays are intrinsically ordered. What would be the point of accessing an array resource via `get(n)` if `n` was going to point at a random value in an unordered collection?

Comment: I'm referring to android loading it from the xml resource, not the Java/Kotlin object itself.

Comment: @Mr.Drew ... Dunno what to tell ya'. Good luck!

Comment: I mean I understand that arrays are ordered, but I can't find exact information in the Android docs to confirm if the order will always be the order they are typed in the xml file. I can't save a map in xml resources, so I'm wondering if two arrays of equal lengths will do if saved in the resource directory. So far in my experimentation that is true, so I understand how you think this in intuitive. I don't know though, maybe the source code uses a different parsing method for large resource files on Android.

Comment: So again, the question isn't if arrays are ordered, but if arrays loaded from xml resources are ordered in the exact same way in memory that they are typed in the xml file when loaded from said file every time on Android.

Comment: @Mr.Drew It’s called an array resource for a reason.

Comment: Yea, I assumed the same thing, but I couldn't find anything on the developer site on this. I guess I'll have to go through the source code to verify. I suppose I'm just searching for a reference for something that probably doesn't need one. :/

Comment: My assumption would be that there's nothing explicit because the word "array" has meaning in this context (both in Java and Android resource files). And again: methods like `get(n)` and `[n]` would be meaningless if order was not guaranteed; you would have no way of knowing what you'd actually be retrieving. I just don't see the issue here, I guess.